# 46 years after the death of King Harold Godwinson

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

46 years after the death of King Harold Godwinson, we're left with this.

Most of these numbers are useless. But some of them aren't. Find them, and use those to find the rest of them. Once you've done that, the single-word answer should be easy to solve.

> 23324
>
> 85317322321754704879777291854038065291180855854683596337771
>
> 78794269525655159909204582004825617358941100876380304651981
>
> 58335819297909357315844266481233150484220623750537589976052

Comment: Does the title provide necessary information to solve the puzzle?  If so, you might consider moving that information into the body of the puzzle as well.

Comment: @puzzledPig Thanks for the advice, I've done exactly that.

Comment: Godwin's law is "Hitler comparisons", Godwinson would be "Son of Hitler".  46 years ago J. Edgar Hoover died.  Hoover was arguably "King" of the US.  And all this feels like a total red herring.

Comment: I don't see many other sentences though

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer (just on the off chance it wasn't obvious to everybody):

> King Harold Godwinson died at the Battle of Hastings in 1066; so 46 years after that would be 1112.

Comment: That's correct, and absolutely vital info for the puzzle if you want to solve it.